# NativeScript-vue build fails when using yarn workspaces

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, yarn-workspaces

I am having problems building a fresh NativeScript-Vue app in a monorepo project. [GitHub repo](https://github.com/xerroxcopy/test-monorepo-ns-vue) here.

### Situation

I would like to share some codes between a Vue.js web app and a NativeScript-Vue native app using yarn workspace. I have seen some NativeScript Slack posts that suggests using yarn workspace. From what I understand, code-sharing by [nativescript-vue-cli-plugin](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-plugin-nativescript-vue) is no longer an option here.

In the GitHub repo, I created `packages/common`, `packages/web` and `packages/native` and started a fresh vue proj in `web` and a fresh NS-Vue proj in `native`.

### Problem

I was able to run web app inside `web` folder by running `npm run serve` but not NativeScript app in `native` folder by running `ns run ios`. Error suggests that symlink isn't working for the unpublished package:

```
% tns run ios
Error while loading nativescript-cloud is: Default commands should be required before child commands
Searching for devices...
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for common@1.0.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'native'
npm ERR! notarget 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mm/.npm/_logs/2020-10-16T05_08_56_467Z-debug.log
Unable to install dependencies. Make sure your package.json is valid and all dependencies are correct. Error is: Command npm failed with exit code 1
```

...but I have a folder named `common` under `/node_modules`, linked to `/packages/common`. Deleting the line `"common":"1.0.0",` in `/packages/native/package.json` allows me to build the app, but that kills the whole point of code-sharing I'm trying to achieve here.

### Question

What am I doing wrong?